# Confirm system dialogs solely by U2F device

Tags: 20.04, pam

I have enabled U2F device authentication for PAM on my Ubuntu 20.04. I have used this approach https://support.yubico.com/hc/en-us/articles/360016649099-Ubuntu-Linux-Login-Guide-U2F and put
configuration into "/etc/pam.d/common-auth". Everything works as expected so I can log in via password AND U2F device touch.

Now I would like to avoid typing password once I am already logged into my account. (I always lock my computer when I leave it and take U2F token with me.)

For sudo I have added into "/etc/pam.d/sudo" line (above line @include common-auth):

```
auth sufficient pam_u2f.so authfile=/etc/u2f_mappings cue
```

After that change, I can confirm sudo just by pressing U2F button. Great.

Is there a way how to achieve the same with system dialogs asking for password? I mean this dialog that appears when I try to install package via Ubuntu Software:

[image: I mean this]

System should keep asking for password + U2F touch during log in.

Comment: I am unable to give you the verified answer, but maybe a hint that will help you is that these prompts are probably controlled by PolicyKit (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polkit), so the file `/etc/pam.d/polkit-1` is probably the place to look for. I don't know anything more.

Answer (score 1):

I accidentally figured this out from your article, and from @raj's comment!  Open up `/etc/pam.d/polkit-1`.  After the `@include`'s, add this line:

```
session required pam_u2f.so authfile=/etc/u2f_mappings cue
```

Thank you for your wonderful article!  I'm using my generic U2F key for everything now.

Comment: You're welcome. This setting does not work for me. It still requires password. I already had U2F confirmation in my dialogues when I added "required" line into /etc/pam.d/common-auth as my article suggests https://www.kubos.cz/2021/01/30/u2f-login-ubuntu

Answer (score 1):

It was basically simple. Based on raj's answer I put:

```
auth sufficient pam_u2f.so authfile=/etc/u2f_mappings cue
```

In front of "@include" section of /etc/pam.d/polkit-1. And now I am required to enter password only on lock/login screen. Once I am logged in, I only press button on donge.

This topic is complex. Please read https://www.kubos.cz/2021/01/30/u2f-login-ubuntu or similar article before you start experimens!